# C++ code - problems with сode execution time

Tags: c++

there is code.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <algorithm> 
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
vector<int> SearchInt(vector<int> vec, int num) {
    vector<int> temp(2);
    sort(begin(vec), end(vec));
    int j = 0;
    for (int i : vec) {
        if (i > num) {
            temp[0] = i;
            temp[1] = j;
            return { temp };

        }
        //cout << i << " !>= " << num << endl   ;
        j++;
    }
    cout << "NO";
    exit(0);

}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> nums(n, 0);
    vector<int> NewNums(n, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> nums[i];
    }
    if (n != nums.size()) {
        cout << "://";
        return 0;
    }
    sort(begin(nums), end(nums));
    NewNums[1] = nums[nums.size() - 1];
    nums.erase(nums.begin() + nums.size() - 1);
    NewNums[0] = nums[nums.size() - 1];
    nums.erase(nums.begin() + nums.size() - 1);

    for (int j = 2; j <= NewNums.size() - 1; j++) {
        NewNums[j] = SearchInt(nums, NewNums[j-1]- NewNums[j-2])[0];
        nums.erase(nums.begin() + SearchInt(nums, NewNums[j] - NewNums[j - 1])[1]);
    }
    if (NewNums[NewNums.size()-1] < NewNums[NewNums.size() - 2] + NewNums[0]) {


        cout << "YES" << endl;
        for (int i : NewNums) {
            cout << i << " ";
        }
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        cout << "NO";
        return 0;
    }
}
```

His task is to check whether it is possible from the given Each number is less than the sum of the two adjacent ones.
(each number is less than both of two adjacent ones)
But there is a problem - with a large number of numbers, the code takes too long. Please help me to optimize it, or just give some advice.
numbers cаn not be null.
time limit: 3.0 s
n <= 500000

You are given n numbers a1, a2,…, an. Is it possible to arrange them in a circle so that each number is strictly less than the sum of its neighbors?

For example, for the array [1,4,5,6,7,8], the left array satisfies the condition, while the right array does not, since 5≥4 + 1 and 8> 1 + 6.
Input data
The first line contains one integer n (3≤n≤105) - the number of numbers.

The second line contains n integers a1, a2,…, an (1≤ai≤109) - the numbers themselves. The given numbers are not necessarily different.

Output
If there is no solution, print "NO" on the first line.

If it exists, print "YES" on the first line. After that, on the second line print n numbers - the elements of the array in the order in which they will stand on the circle. The first and last elements you print are considered neighbors on the circle. If there are multiple solutions, output any of them. You can print a circle starting with any of the numbers.

Comment: "the code takes too long" for what? What is the speed you need to achieve? What is the speed you do achieve? How did you measure?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but `n != nums.size()` should never be true.

Comment: Regarding your problem, it seems to me that you're doing some kind of "competitive" programming, and for many problems there are three common solutions: Either find out a formula where you don't need loops to calculate values; Or use [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), which basically means you calculate values once, and store (cache) them if they will be used again; And the last is to come up with an algorithm that doesn't require so many iterations or nested loops.

Comment: Lastly, please copy-paste the full and complete competition description into the question itself, as well as provide to the problem (unless it's to a pay-walled or registration-only site).

Comment: This gives an impression of being a challenge with an online judge. They are very often created so that a too literal implementation of the described situations will fail the timit limit. Solutions are either using math instead of simulation or focusing on exactly only the needed answer. For example, avoid creating and copying large data structurey (vecors) if a Yes/No answer is needed, then try to drop all unneeded information as soon as possible.

Comment: @Yunnosch, The problem is that when you answer "YES", you need to specify the order, and I can't even imagine how this can be done without a loop.

Comment: @undefined "...so that each number is less than two adjacent ones..." Could you post an original description. Each number is less than the sum of the two adjacent ones?

Comment: @Yunnosch, Unfortunately the original is in Russian. And I indicated everything I could. And yes, "Each number is less than the sum of the two adjacent ones?" perhaps there is a correct translation.

Comment: @undefined If you mean that "Each number is less than the sum of the two adjacent ones" then please edit your question accordingly. From current description "each number is less than two adjacent ones" the former is not clear at all - the first thought is that  "each number is less than both of two adjacent ones" ("каждое число меньше любого из двух соседних") - which is obviously not possible.

Comment: @undefined Also it is of high importance if the numbers are natural numbers (positive integers) or if they can be zero or negative integers or real numbers (floating point numbers). I guess it should be specified in original russian text for this problem.

Comment: @SergeDundich, Edited, I hope now everything is correct.

Comment: @undefined You didn't answer if those numbers are always positive according to problem description ("натуральные числа" согласно условию задачи) or they may be zero or negative. It is important because positive-only problem is much easier than mixed case problem.

Comment: @SergeDundich. I nevertheless decided to set all the conditions completely, if there are errors - Google translated the translator :)
Unfortunately, I cannot throw a link. (Post Eedited)

Comment: @undefined Oh at long last you did what you had to do from the very beginning - post actual problem description. So actually numbers are not only natural numbers but integers in range from 1 to 109. What was the reason to avoid this info in the very first edition of your question? (Почему сразу было условие задачи не написать?)

Answer (score 1):

First I'll only briefly analyze technical shortcomings of your code - without analyzing its meaning. After that I'll write my solution of the problem you defined.

Performance problems of your code are due to some strange decisions:

(1) passing `std::vector<int>` by value and not by reference to `SearchInt` function - this implies allocating and copying of the whole array on each function invocation,

(2) call `SearchInt` two times per loop iteration in function `main` instead of only one,

(3) `sort` array within each invocation of `SearchInt` - it is already sorted before the loop.

To be honest your code feels ridiculously time-consuming. I'm only wondering if that was your intention to make it as slow as you possibly can...

I will not analyze correctness of your code according to problem description. To be honest even after fixing technical shortcomings your code seems to me utterly sub-optimal and quite incomprehensible - so it is just easier to solve the problem from scratch to me.

The answer to the problem (as defined in your description) is

- **YES** - if the biggest number is smaller than the sum of the second big number and the third big number
- **NO** - otherwise (obviously - as there are NO two numbers in your sequence excluding the biggest number that sum to anything bigger than the biggest number)

This follows from the fact that all numbers are positive (in range 1 - 109 according to newly found problem description).

If the answer is *YES* then to make a circle that satisfies the problem description you just need in a sorted sequence of input numbers switch places of the biggest number and the next big one - that's all.

I'll assume that the number of items should be `3 ≤ n ≤ 500000`. At one point in your description you claim `n <= 500000`. Later though you claim - **quote**:

> The first line contains one integer n (3≤n≤105) - the number of numbers.

(Who knows what was in actual task description so I'll pick wider interval... Maybe you meant `3≤n≤10^5` or `3≤n≤1e5` - aka 10 to the power 5 aka 100000?... Whatever...)

Here is my code for that (for slightly relaxed input format - I'm not checking if number of items is on a separate line and that all items are on the same line - but all correct inputs will be parsed just fine):

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::multiset<unsigned> input_set;
    unsigned long n;

    if( !( std::cin >> n ) )
    {
        std::cerr << "Input error - failed to read number of items." << std::endl;
        return 2;
    }

    if( n - 3UL > 500000UL - 3UL )
    {
        std::cerr << "Wrong number of items value - " << n << " (must be from 3 to 500000)" << std::endl;
        return 2;
    }

    for( unsigned long j = 0; j < n; ++j )
    {
        unsigned x;

        if( !( std::cin >> x ) )
        {
            std::cerr << "Input error - failed to read item #" << j << std::endl;
            return 2;
        }
    
        if( x - 1U > 109U - 1U )
        {
            std::cerr << "Wrong item #" << j << " value - " << x << " (must be from 1 to 109)" << std::endl;
            return 2;
        }

        input_set.insert(x);
    }

    std::multiset<unsigned>::const_reverse_iterator it = input_set.rbegin();
    std::multiset<unsigned>::const_reverse_iterator it0 = it;
    std::multiset<unsigned>::const_reverse_iterator it1 = ++it;

    // solution exists if and only if the biggest number is smaller
    // than the sum of the second big and the third big numbers
    if( *it0 >= *it1 + *++it )
    {
        std::cout << "NO" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Circle: " << *it1 << ' ' << *it0;

    do
    {
        std::cout << ' ' << *it;
    }
    while( ++it != input_set.rend() );

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```